# Find a sequence $b_n $ so that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{b_n} = (P)$

Tags: real-analysis

Given a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ with the terms $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}-...$

and the terms $(P) = 1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{12}+...$

Find a sequence $b_n $ so that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{b_n} = (P)$

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence $a_{n}$ could be rewritten as $\frac{1}{2k-1} - \frac{1}{2k}$

Now think about a way to rewrite your new sequence $b_{n}$. One possible solution could be
$\frac{1}{2k-1} - \frac{1}{2(2k-1)} - \frac{1}{4k}$